# ARP with Layer 2 managed switch

Tags: networking

Say I have a switch hosting a 10.10.1.x/24 subnet, and a device plugs into it that is manually configured to send as if on 192.168.1.x/24.  When the malconfigured device ARPs out for say, 192.168.1.150, will the switch do anything special here?  Assuming another malconfigured host replies, will the switch prevent the communication by forwarding the packets to a default gateway or for any other reason?

I imagine one of two things might happen here?

1) Communication works fine as long as there is ARP replies.  Proxy ARP might hinder this if another device replies for the out-of-scope 192* addresses.

2) Switch reads IP out of subnet and arbitrarily forwards it down whatever port the gateway is on.  Gateway always gets packet.

Comment: Remember, Layer 2 devices don't know anything about Layer 3, so that means they don't understand ARP or IP addresses.  All of their processing happens at the Ethernet level.

Comment: The switch does have me specify a default gateway.  I think this switch knows some things Layer 3.  My situation is odd and I'm not sure what would happen.

Comment: Yes, being a managed switch, it may still have an IP address and management interface, but if it is a Layer 2 switch, it should only deal with the Ethernet frames and not touch the IP layer.